# Can Evolution and Thunderbird share an addressbook?

Tags: sync, evolution, thunderbird

I'm trying to get my new Android phone running without speaking to Google or sending them my data. For the moment, I've got Funambol Running, but Funambol doesn't have a Thunderbird client. They do have an Evolution plugin, however. I'm not prepared to switch over to Evolution, because I really like Thunderbird and have it all set up just so.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to get Evolution to read my Thunderbird address book or vice versa. That way I can sync Thunderbird to Evolution, Evolution to Funambol, Funambol to Android.

I'm open to better solutions here, too.

Comment: Seems that thus far, the answer is "no". http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2011/03/17/prior-art-and-rdfd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Thunderbird uses EDS by default in 11.10, which means that it is shared with Evolution. EDS currently has issues with DesktopCouch addressbooks, but others seem to work nicely.

Comment: When I asked, I was still on Natty Narwhal, but indeed, Evolution and Thunderbird are now able to share addressbooks.

Comment: I guess I didn't look at the date of your question when I answered. :)

Comment: Hah. Well ... you answered almost a year ago. I just noticed that I hadn't accepted an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually save and load adressbooks via dropbox or similar services! There is a dropbox app for android, should work. But that's not what you want, is it?

Comment: I really would like to sync them, so that as contacts are updated/added/removed that's reflected in Thunderbird and on my phone.